# onFocusChange code example?

Tags: android

I have a form with 2 fields where you can enter in either months or years.  How do I setup the form so that if you enter in the years, the months edittext field will be automatically calculated and entered into it's own box.  Likewise, I want the years to be calculated if you entered in the months

Can anyone give me sample code for this?

Answer (score 19):

You have two ways to do this:

1. Do character by character processing of one field to calculate the other field

   For this you may use the addTextChangedListener with a text watcher where you change the onTextChanged method to process the data.

   ```
   //from editHandle = (EditText) findViewById(R.id. <<your EditText>> );

   editHandle.addTextChangedListener(redoWatcher);

   // listener
   private TextWatcher redoWatcher = new TextWatcher() {


       public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
               int after) {
       }

       @Override   
       public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
               int count) {
           recalculate();
       }

       @Override
       public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

       }

   };
   ```

Now you can write the recalculate method to process the data.

2 . The other method is to calculate the data when the user changes focus to the other field.

Here you need to use the onFocusChangeListener:

```
<Your EditView>.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        recalculate();
    }
});
```

Either way, depending on the design you might want to check for valid input.